# How to substitute cp1250 specific characters to utf-8 in Vim

Tags: vim

I have some central european characters in cp1250 encoding in Vim. When I change encoding with *set encoding=utf-8* they appear like `<d0>` and such. How can I substitute over the entire file those characters for what they should be, i.e. Đ, in this case?

Answer (score 3):

As sidyll said, you *should really* use iconv for the purpose. Iconv knows stuff. It knows all the hairy encodings, onscure code-points, katakana, denormalized, canonical forms, compositions, nonspacing characters and the rest.

```
:%!iconv --from-code cp1250 --to-code utf-8
```

or shorter

```
:%!iconv -f cp1250 -t utf-8
```

to filter the whole buffer. If you do

```
:he xxd
```

You'll get a sample of how to automatically encode on buffer load/save if you wanted.

`iconv -l` will list you all (many: 1168 on my system) encodings it accepts/knows about.

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 2):

The `iconv()` function may be useful:

```
iconv({expr}, {from}, {to})             *iconv()*
        The result is a String, which is the text {expr} converted
        from encoding {from} to encoding {to}.
        When the conversion fails an empty string is returned.
        The encoding names are whatever the iconv() library function
        can accept, see ":!man 3 iconv".
        Most conversions require Vim to be compiled with the |+iconv|
        feature.  Otherwise only UTF-8 to latin1 conversion and back
        can be done.
        This can be used to display messages with special characters,
        no matter what 'encoding' is set to.  Write the message in
        UTF-8 and use:
            echo iconv(utf8_str, "utf-8", &enc)
        Note that Vim uses UTF-8 for all Unicode encodings, conversion
        from/to UCS-2 is automatically changed to use UTF-8.  You
        cannot use UCS-2 in a string anyway, because of the NUL bytes.
        {only available when compiled with the +multi_byte feature}
```

Comment: @sehe: Ah, that's much better! Specially if it's needed to convert the entire buffer. @Rook, check that, you only need a bit of Vim filter (`!`) magic. @sehe, why not to post it as an answer so we can up vote?

Comment: To be honest, I like the 'simplicity' of calling a filter program, but I liked your suggestioin of using a builtin function a lot! I didn't know it was there :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `encoding` to the value of your file's encoding and `termencoding` to UTF-8. See [The vim mbyte documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/mbyte.html#mbyte-encoding).